# How to initial the function "tf.keras.layers.prelu"

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I've read some papers about activation funcation PReLU, and the parameter alpha can be initilized to the value 0.25. How to initialize the alpha in function "tf.keras.layers.prelu"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer this official document for all parameters.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/PReLU

```
tf.keras.layers.PReLU(
    alpha_initializer='zeros', alpha_regularizer=None, alpha_constraint=None,
    shared_axes=None, **kwargs
)
```

To initialise with 0.25, use this

```
  tf.keras.layers.PReLU(alpha_initializer=tf.initializers.constant(0.25))
```

Comment: Happy to help:)